# Laravel migrate ends up in wrong database

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I have the following settings in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=unwa
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=NotForEverybody
```

When I run

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Everything seems to be ok. But when I look at my target database "unwa", it is empty.
A die and dump revealed, that I was connected to another database "auction" that happens to be the first (alphabetically) database. I find all my tables in the "auction" database.

How can I correctly configure my target database "unwa"?

Comment: Check your `config/database.php`, what does it say for mysql.database?

Comment: 'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),

Comment: When you run `php artisan tinker` and `env('DB_DATABASE)` what do you get ? if you get `unwa` then check your default database in `config/database.php` if you have multiple declared and check your migrations, maybe some statement are forcing the database change.

Comment: You can try `grep -R auction .` from your project root to try to find where it's pulling `auction` from.

Comment: keep in mind that all your service providers will run before performing the actual migration so if you change the default database there then you might see this happening

Comment: For env('DB_DATABASE') in tinker I get "unwa". The default database in config/database.php is  env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')

Comment: The only occurrence of "auction" in the entire project directory is in a javascript file chunk-vendors.a7f629a4.js, That does not change the database, as far as I can tell.

Comment: As an experiment I created a new database "aaa" and reran the migration, just to find out about the first database theory. But the tables end up in "auction" non the less.

Comment: Did you at any time use `auction` as `DB_DATABASE` in your project? Cached config maybe? (Try to run `php artisan config:clear`). Are you checking the correct mysql server?

Comment: no. auction is a database that does not even involve laravel or eloquent. php artisan config:clear does not change the outcome of the migration.

Comment: are you sure you are running the artisan command on the right directory?

Comment: yes. The problem was the environment variable DATABASE_URL. It overrides the configuration in .env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a system environment variable **DATABASE_URL** that would point to the auction database. This is why it was targeted by the migrations and it could not be found anywhere in the project. Once I removed that environment variable, the migration started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your cache
"php artisan optimize:clear"

Comment: I tried it, but the tables are still in "auction" after the migrate.